# What is causing this error on loading a project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Every other time (or so) lately, when I open a particular project in VS Ultimate 2012 (Version 11.0.60315.01 Update 2), it first hangs (No Response) until I have to Ctrl+Alt+Del out of it. Then, when I open it again, it gives me this err msg:

An error was encountered while opening associated documents the last time this solution was loaded. Document load is being skipped during this solution load in order to avoid that error.

And after that it's fine for the rest of the session (or seems to be). What sort of "associated documents" might this be, and should I get rid of them?

Note: When it opens on the second try (after the err msg about the failure on the first try), none of my files are open in the project - I have to open them from the Solution Exploder.

### UPDATE

I have a suspicion this is actually a serious problem, as after the latest such "experience," my site doesn't work as it should - it compiles and it runs, but it's not fully functional and WebMatrix seems to be confused about it (generating all kinds of vague and nonsensical errors and warnings in the report).

Comment: Is is a solution or a project. If a solution does it have multiple projects? If so then can you edit the .SLN file and remove the project one by one until you can find out whci one it is. When you get to one project manually delete it's output folders (usually called bin & obj) in windows and try and reload. Also if there are documents in solution  directly then you can edit them out manually too.

Comment: It's just one project.

Comment: Please show your sln file.

Comment: There is no .sln file. There is a Packages.config and a Web.config...

Comment: in that case I suggest using procmon utility to see what files it's accessing or trying to access.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .suo file?

Comment: @Cameron: That (an *.suo file) I also don't have.

Comment: @ClayShannon Have you any extensions/addins installed, could be worth disabling those first before doing more radical changes.